# Instagram LED Notifications

Tags: notifications, notification-led, instagram

I have a custom ROM on my S3, but that shouldn't really be the issue here. I am on JB 4.2.2.

With my custom ROM I am able to set up different colors of the LED notification for each app that I want. However, this works for every single app I get notifications for except for Instagram. I still get the notifications for Instagram, the LED just doesn't light up when I receive them or they are still sitting in my tray. For Twitter I had to change the settings in the app itself to allow the LED to work, but for every other app, it has been default once I added the settings in my custom ROM. Instagram seems to be handling notifications a little bit differently from the other applications, because it doesn't wake up my phone when I get a notification either. But, I have a desktop application that shows me a pop-up on my computer when I receive notifications on my phone, and it notifies me for every notification, even Instagram.

I want to know if there is anything that I can do within Instagram or maybe somewhere in the phones settings to enable the LED to light up when I receive a new notification from Instagram.

Thanks.

Comment: What rom are you using?

Comment: @Nick it's a custom AOKP by Task650. Doesn't really have a name but all the settings are the same as plain AOKP.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Light Flow](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rageconsulting.android.lightflow&hl=en)? It does the what the same thing as the custom rom does and Instagram is on their list of [support apps](http://www.folioflow.com/ff/page/website/lightflow/pageId/2283) for their Pro version.

Comment: I really don't want to have to pay just to receive notification from Instagram, but if I don't figure anything else out, thanks for the option.